# Amplify @hasMany relationship return null

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

This are my first question here.

I have this schema on amplify

```js
type Products @model {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  description: String!
  variations: [Variation] @hasMany(indexName: "byProduct", fields: ["id"])
}

type Variation @model {
  id: ID!
  productId: ID! @index(name: "byProduct")
  name: String!
  image: String!
  quantity: Int!
}
```

When I test the query on AppSync this return the variations, but when I use

```js
const result = (await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(gql.listProducts))).data.listProducts.items;
```

or with DataStore like this

```js
await DataStore.query(Products)
```

return a null or empty

```json
    variations: { nextToken: null, startedAt: null },
```

Someone with the same issue ? or maybe I was missing something?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check type of Products in local when await DataStore.query(Products)
and value of listProducts in gql when API.graphql.
I think you are missing a few fields.